# ARKit Occlusion Invisible Plane Reference Image

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, occlusion

I'm trying to hide `SCNPlanes` behind an invisible `SCNPlane` the same size as the `ARReferenceImage`. Using `SCNAction` I want to reveal those planes next to the `ARReferenceImage`

**Problem**

The `SCNPlanes` are still visible and not hidden.

This is the code I use for Occlusion:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                     height:referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.writesToDepthBuffer = true
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = .alpha
planeNode.renderingOrder = -1
```

This is my code:
https://gist.github.com/magicmikek/0444fbd5c146131ad08fbb19875fbc83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invisible `planeNode` can't have the same `Y value` as the `SCNPlanes` it wants to hide using occlusion.

**Solution**

nodeBehind.position.y = -0.005